# How to draw multiple bitmaps vertically, one below the other

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

I'm trying to draw a bunch of bitmaps vertically one below the other like this :

Original `Bitmap` :

[image]

Result expected :

[image]

Code :

```
   int repeater = 4;
   Bitmap bitmapTextSticker = ImageUtils.drawable2Bitmap(ResourceUtils.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
   Bitmap background = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapTextSticker.getWidth(), bitmapTextSticker.getHeight() * repeater, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
   Canvas canvas = new Canvas(background);
   int top = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < repeater; i++) {
          top = (i == 0 ? 0 : top + bitmapTextSticker.getHeight());
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapTextSticker, 0f, top, null);
     }
```

**The above code is working, but the output is cropped.**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I didn't set the `density` for the bitmap and the `canvas` :

```
  ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < repeater; i++) bitmaps.add(bmp);
        int height = 0;
        for (Bitmap map : bitmaps) height += map.getHeight();

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvas.setDensity(DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM);
        bitmap.setDensity(DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM);
        int drawHeight = 0;
        for (Bitmap map : bitmaps) {
            if (map != null) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(map, 0, drawHeight, null);
                drawHeight += map.getHeight();
            }
        }
        return bitmap;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm missing something in your question, but all you have to do is change the `top` coordinate for each bitmap when calling drawBitmap(). In your specific code, just add:

```
top += height;
```

inside the for loop

Edit: from your updated question, it sounds like a Bitmap scaling issue, not a problem with position. Even your 1st bitmap is cropped. So, you should probably use a different canvas.drawbitmap() method:

```
public void drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Rect src,  RectF dst, Paint paint)
```

You can specify the dimensions of the destination Rect, which should let it scale properly. So, your code should be:

```
for(...){
   ...
   RectF dest = new RectF(new Rect(0, top, bitmapTextSticker.getWidth(), bitmapTextSticker.getHeight()));
   canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapTextSticker, null, dest, null);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've updated my question, could you please check it again

Comment: That sounds like an issue with drawing the Bitmaps themselves, and not with their positioning. It sounds like somehow the width/height of the bitmapTextSticker aren't being drawn properly

Comment: massive thanks for your help, but unfortunately it does not work, now, only one bitmap being drawn in the top

Comment: sorry, that was a typo on my end -- I forgot to set the top coordinate in my Rect (I left it at 0, but it should have been the adjusted `top` variable)